# How to make Urls in Rails seofriendly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

How can i realize seo friendly urls?

Instead

```
http://mysite.com/articles/show/2
```

i would like to use the articlename instead the id

i.e.

```
mysite.com/articles/show/articlename
```

or somehow combine id and articlename like this

```
mysite.com/articles/show/articlename-2
```

i'm a rails newbie so perhaps you could give me short advice where to change
something with what code?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your article controller, probably in `app/controllers/articles.rb`. You probably have a method named `show` which looks up an article by id with something like this:

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

If you know the id is going to be the title of the post instead of its id, you can instead look up your article using

```
@article = Article.find_by_title(params[:id])
```

This will allow you to use somewhat ugly URLs like `/articles/show/This+is+the+title`. If you want to make a slightly nicer URL, you could add a column to your article table (called, say, `seo_title`) to store the title translated to lowercase with underscores, yielding something like `this_is_the_title`.

Comment: thanks that works good, but when i use this in the View  (<%= link_to "Details", :action => "show",
    :title => article.title %> it gives me an url like this http://localhost:3000/articles/show?title=articlename but it should be articles/show/articlename

Comment: @and: If you do it this way, the parameter is still called `id` (even though it contains the title and not the id), so you need to pass `:id => article.title` to `link_to`. If you want the parameter to be called title, you need to change the routes.

Comment: yes realized this, works good now also for destroy action, the only problem still is the edit action. i get the error Couldn't find Bookmark with ID=Thisismyfirstarticletitle. the edit.html.erb looks like this <% form_for :article, :url => {:action => "update",
:id => @article.title} do |f| %>

Comment: was a problem with the update action. also wanted to use there this version @bookmark = Bookmark.find_by_title(params[:id]) but seemed that only this works here. still not understand why find_by_title not works for the update action when you i.e. just change another field of the record than the title?

Answer (score 0):

@and

Your question is at once both simple and yet difficult. Best you check out this more mature Stack Overflow post to find your answer:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723765/how-do-i-make-the-urls-in-ruby-on-rails-seo-friendly-knowing-a-vendor-name/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723765/how-do-i-make-the-urls-in-ruby-on-rails-seo-friendly-knowing-a-vendor-name/3844058#3844058)

It has more examples and more options. While find_by_title is an option, it is far from your best option.